# I have a DXF file that I need to attribute a map to, to locate it in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, georeferencing

I have recieved a DWG file with no location information other than the parcel numbers.
I was told to open it in QGIS (I have QGIS 3.14), install the plugin HCMGIS and open a Google Satellite BaseMap to locate it.
However when I did all this, the map did not appear.
I am new to QGIS and don't know if there is more to do in order to reference this drawing.

I would like some guidance through the process of it.

I have read online that you need to use and OpenLayers but that doesn't appear in the plugins manager anyway.

Comment: The title states you have a DXF, but the body states DWG. Please [Edit] the question to clarify what data you have and what exact steps you took.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level what you want to do is

- Import your DXF/DWG file
- Add in a basemap using the HCMGIS plugin
- Georeference the DXF file against the basemap.

Break your problems down into the above steps.

- Can you import/bring in the DXF/DWG file? Can you see it on the map canvas?
- Can you load the HCMGIS plugin. It should allow you to add in a Open Street Maps basemap.
- Read here for Georeferencing. [LINK](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192700/how-georeference-a-dxf-file-in-qgis-2-14?rq=1)