# Overlay Text Generated in Illustrator Over Map And Export to KML in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, dxf, illustrator

I have some text that I generated in Illustrator, outlined, and then exported to a DXF. I need to assign spatial data so that I can export that DXF from QGIS to KML with correct lat/lon coordinates. The exported KML will be imported into ground control software to create a multicopter flight plan. When finished, I should be able to fly along the outline of the text in the sky.

I grabbed a Shapefile from the US Census bureau so I have some reference to work with. When I import the DXF, for one, the scale is entirely incorrect.

[image: zoom to fit]

For starters, how do I scale this? I'm not coming up with much help in the docs. I'm imagining the KML export should be straightforward once I manage getting the vector data imported and formatted correctly.

Comment: You might need to georeference your text in the DXF before exporting - QGIS has georeferencing tools to do this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22691/georeferencing-dxf-using-qgis