# Import Illustrator/Inkscape svg into qgis

Tags: qgis, scale, illustrator, affine-transformation, inkscape

I tried to import lines from svg into qgis 3.x by using dxf format. The problem is that the scale of dxf is of course not the right one (a few centimeters whereas my map is kilometers long).

I tried to look at affine transformation but it is very annoying to use and doesn't really quite work as expected.

Do you have any advice on how to import the drawings into qgis and how to scale them properly?

Or only on the last step, on the scaling and translating issue?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22691/georeferencing-dxf-using-qgis

Comment: Yes indeed but this plugin doesn't exist on QGIS 3.x. I used it with QGIS 2.18 but it moves away my figure (it just multiplies the coordinates by the factors in the matrix which makes it very uneasy to place precisely the elements).

Comment: @Mapperz No idea of other techniques?