# Adding coordinate system to .dwg in order to convert to .shp

Tags: qgis, dwg

I have a number .DWG files that appear to have no georeferencing or coordinate system attached. They were probably created in line with OS master mapping.

My aim is to try and convert the lines in these drawings to .shp in order to add to an existing project within QGIS. To do this I am assuming that I need to apply a coordinate system as well as reference a point within the dwg or shape to that reference system. (As you can tell, I am guessing)

I am using NanoCad to open the .dwg

Is there a way to do what I want to achieve, and if there is, what is the best way to  apply a coordinate system (In NanoCad, or convert and then in QGIS).

Comment: you  can georeference your dwg file (with some plugins in qgis) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22691/georeferencing-dxf-using-qgis

Comment: What do the coordinates look like when you add one of the DWGs to QGIS? That should tell you whether you need to define the coordinate reference system only or whether you need to georeference it first.